# Ace Editor: How do I get the value of an editor without line breaks?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Using ace editor has been a challenge to say the least. Though I'm able to get the value of the editor, I can't seem to do it without either encountering a bug or having the escape characters included.

Is there a method that will provide me with the full text of the editor, minus the escape characters?

`getAllLines()` returns a console error stating that it's not a function

`getTextRange()` also returns an error stating it's not a function

`removeNewLine()` returns a cryptic error that I can't seem to trace

So is there a standard, working method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function for doing that, but you could get the value and remove the line-breaks yourself.

```
var multiLineVal = editor.getValue();
var singleLineVal = multiLineVal.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
```